# Loopback HasManyThrough between PostgreSQL model and MongoDB yields empty GET result (REST API)

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, loopbackjs

I'm trying to make a `HasManyThrough` between PostgreSQL models (`Customer`, `Purchase`) and MongoDB model (`Product`). I have followed the guide in https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasManyThrough+relations and managed to add some data through boot script (I have checked in the PostgreSQL that the record are populated correctly).

The problem is I always get empty result (no error) whenever I try to GET the models using `/Customers/{id}/products`. The strange things is that count API `/Customers/{id}/products/count` and `/Customers/{id}/products/{fk}` are working perfectly.

Could anyone help to point out what is problem or advise a way to debug the issue?

Here are my model definitions:

**model-config.json**

```
{
  ...
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "postgresDS",
    "public": false
  },
  "Product": {
    "dataSource": "mongoDS",
    "public": true
  },
  "Customer": {
    "dataSource": "postgresDS",
    "public": true
  },
  "Purchase": {
    "dataSource": "postgresDS",
    "public": false
  },
  ...
}
```

**customer.json**

```
{
  "name": "Customer",
  "base": "User",
  "strict": true,
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    ...
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "products": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Product",
      "foreignKey": "customerId",
      "through": "Purchase",
      "keyThrough": "productId"
    }
  },
  ...
```

}

**purchase.json**

```
{
  "name": "Purchase",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    ...
  },
  "relations": {
    "customer": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Customer",
      "foreignKey": "customerId"
    },
    "product": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Product",
      "foreignKey": "productId"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

**product.json**

```
{
  "name": "Product",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  ...
  "properties": {
    ...
  },
  "relations": {
    "customers": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Customer",
      "foreignKey": "productId",
      "through": "Purchase",
      "keyThrough": "customerId"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

**Update**

I've tried to debug using `DEBUG=loopback:connector:* node .` and found below entries when trying to invoke `/Customers/{id}/products`. I think the problem lies in the `[Object]` which is used in MongoDB query. But I have no idea how to debug it.

```
loopback:connector:mongodb all +3ms Product { where: { id: { inq: [Object] } } }
loopback:connector:mongodb MongoDB: model=Product command=find +1ms [ { _id: { '$in': [Object] } }, [Function] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it work by mapping mongodb `_id` to a property `id` as described in https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/issues/52

**product.json**

```
{
    "name": "Product",
    "base": "PersistedModel",
    "idInjection": true,
    "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
    },
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "string",
            "id": true,
            "mongodb": {
                "field": "_id"
            }
        },
        ...
    },
    "relations": {
        "customers": {
            "type": "hasMany",
            "model": "Customer",
            "foreignKey": "productId",
            "through": "Purchase",
            "keyThrough": "customerId"
        }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `customerId` and `productId` properties in `Purchase` model.

```
//purchase.json
{
  "name": "Purchase",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    ...
    "productId": {
       "type": "object"
    },
    "customerId": {
       "type": "object"
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "customer": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Customer",
      "foreignKey": "customerId"
    },
    "product": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Product",
      "foreignKey": "productId"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Set types of properties according to specific db.

**UPDATE**

Also `product.json`  needs modification

```
//product.json
{
  "name": "Product",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  ...
  "properties": {
    ...
  },
  "relations": {
    "customers": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Customer",
      "foreignKey": "productId",
      "through": "Purchase"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately it's still not working. I've tried using `object` and `string` for the type but the result is still empty. Do you have any working example?

Comment: I have updated my model definitions as you suggested (reflected in my question as well) but unfortunately it's still not working

Comment: @YohanesGultom I still see wrong definition for `Product`

Comment: @YohanesGultom `Product` definition should be the same as `Customer` but in reverse

Comment: Ups, my bad, it's a typo (fixed in question). I have done as you suggested but unfortunately it's still the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122388/discussion-between-ebrahim-pasbani-and-yohanes-gultom).

Comment: @YohanesGultom Do you still have the properties I mentioned before in `Purchase` model? (it should be threre)

Comment: I finally made it work by adding custom mapping to mongo `_id` (see my answer). It still works even without redefining foreign key properties in `purchase.json`. Thanks for your help

Comment: @YohanesGultom Cool. But fixing `Product` definition was necessary